Python Package Optional Sub-package if Optional Extras Specified
Say I have created a python project foobar with the following layout:
foobar
├── __init__.py
├── core/
├── network/
└── plotting/


I would like to have pip install foobar to install only the core part of the package, along with core dependencies:

foobar
├── __init__.py
└── core/


I would like to have pip install foobar[plotting] to install plotting capabilities and extra dependencies on-top of the core installation:

foobar
├── __init__.py
├── core/
└── plotting/


I would like to have pip install foobar[all] to install everything:

foobar
├── __init__.py
├── core/
├── network/
└── plotting/

Dependency groups for the above scenarios seem simple enough to define in the pyproject.toml file:
[project]
name = "foobar"
...
dependencies = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
network = [
    "requests",
]
plotting = [
    "PyQt6",
    "pyqtgraph",
]
all = [
    "foobar[network,plotting]",
]
dev = [
    "foobar[all]",
    "pytest",
    "ruff",
    "black",
]

But it's unclear to me whether the package contents can be installed as I intend through some kind of definition in the pyproject.toml file.  How can this be accomplished?

Python doesn't support partial installation of a package, and the extras flag is meant to specify additional optional dependencies, which will then pull in extra packages.  So you may convert your monolithic package into separate packages and use extras to pull them in.

You cannot do that from a single source tree. Every subpackage you want must be its own separate package built from a separate source tree.
